Python-Logging does not write info in the log file
I try to write a error or info logs to a log file. Here is the basicConfig
logging.basicConfig(
        filename="script_log.log",
        encoding="utf-8",
        filemode="a",
        format="{asctime} - {levelname} - {message}",
        style="{",
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
    )


If I write script as below, the warning message is written in the script_log.log file without issue.
def getCertList(ip_address, username, password, file_path,prompt='admin:'):
    # Connect to Server
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False,
                           allow_agent=False, timeout=30)
        interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh_client, timeout=360,
                                        display=False)  # "display=True" is just to show you what script does in real time. While in production you can set it to False
        interact.expect(prompt)
    except:
        logging.warning(f"Unable to connect to server {ip_address}, check network connectivity please.", exc_info=True)

If at the end of the script, everything is working, I would like to write a info logging like this, it won't write the line in the log file.
logging.info("All Information has been collected sucessfully. ")

Did I miss anything?
I tried to use with open to open the script_log.log file and write the line, it worked, so it should be the logging.info problem, but I could not figure out.

The root logger has a default level of WARNING. Thus it will not show any INFO level logging messages. Add an argument level=logging.INFO to your basicConfig call.

What they said in the documentation

This question is similar to: python logging set level in basicConfig. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
